# Fix type erasure after matching a list

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Consider the following recursive function:

```
def example (param: List[Int]): Int = {
    case Nil => 0
    case x :: xs => example(xs)
}
```

This leads to the following error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[Any]
[error]  required: List[Int]
```

From the declaration of parameters it should be clear that the result of the decomposition will be an `Int` and a `List[Int]`, but obviously the compiler does not think so. How can I make this work?

Comment: You're missing a `param match` after the `=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have missed param match statement. Try this:

```
def example (param: List[Int]): Int = param match {
  case Nil => 0
  case x :: xs => example(xs)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer indicates, you're missing a `param match` after the `=`. Alternately, you can avoid the `param match` part by defining `example` as a function value :

```
val example: List[Int] => Int = {
  case Nil => 0
  case x :: xs => example(xs)
}
```

The block with `case` statements is treated as anonymous function by the compiler.